# Returning objects from list to a listbox

Tags: c#, string, winforms, oop, listbox

I've been trying to create a method which adds items in to the listbox. 
There is a class Member and each Member belongs to the ProjectGroup. Member has a method getName() which returns string name. 
So the problem appears when I try to add more than 1 person. The listbox gets stuck at first person in the list, and nothing new appears. The code looks like this:

```
public class ProjectGroup
    {
        List<Member> members = new List<Member>();

        public void addMember(string name)
        {
            Member newPerson = new Member(name);

            members.Add(newPerson);
        }

        public string getInfo()
        {
            foreach (Member item in members)
            {
                return item.getName();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

And the code in the form:

```
        ProjectGroup group = new ProjectGroup();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = textBox1.Text;

            lbStudents.Items.Clear();
            textBox1.Text = "";

            group.addMember(name);

            lbStudents.Items.Add(group.getInfo());
        }
```

Comment: `return something;`,  returns something and exists from the method. [return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: You may want to return a `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` from the method. In case of `IEnumerable`, [`yield return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is what you are looking for.

Comment: What type of object you want to add to your ListBox ? If you just want to add the same name, that you add to your group also add to the listbox, it's just `Items.Add(name) ;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<string> getInfo()
    {
       var result= new List<string>();
        foreach (Member item in members)
        {
          result.Add(item.getName());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

and change it:

```
lbStudents.Items.AddRange(group.getInfo());
```